# How can I obtain connectedAndroidTestDebug logcat from commandline gradlew?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-logcat

After setting up some tests I can run them with `./gradlew  --debug connectedAndroidTestDebug` and see that they work. When I modify one test to fail and see what I get, gradle produces a pretty HTML with statistics about what tests failed, but it doesn't show what assert condition failed nor in which source code/line. The description for each test is:

```
Test failed to run to completion.
Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to junit.framework.AssertionFailedError''.
Check device logcat for details*.
```

However I don't know how I can get the logcat of the device for this test. I can open `adb logcat` in another window but there is plenty messages that I don't see the results I'm interested in, plus this requires me to be watching the unit test happen, and I want to get the results. Is this possible?

If using Android's log is that bad, is there any kind of software which runs a local server where I can send logs to it?

Comment: If you are using a Mac you could view and disect your logs with LogRabbit. This is how you can do a raw log import: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n8mgNp9tvqs

Comment: What logs do you need? `./gradlew  --info connectedAndroidTestDebug`

Comment: does that just dump out additional gradle logs? or does it actually pull in info from logcat?

Comment: @CasualT just additional gradle logs, no useful test runtime logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be quite useful if it pulled off the logs itself, but unfortunately I haven't found a built in way to do that either. :(

I usually will dump it out to a file using something like this post-build:

```
adb logcat -d > latestLogCat.txt
```

And then parse through that.

(if you call `adb logcat -c` before the tests then the log will be a bit shorter).

Comment: Nice tip about the ``-c``, indeed I've ended up dumping and parsing the log myself.